# Adobe Flash App based Linux Distro

Tags: adobe-flash, small-distribution

What would be the best way to create a small Linux image that just runs a single Flash SWF on startup (full screen)? Are there distros catered to something like this, or is my best bet manually slimming down an image and then adding something into one of the startup scripts?

Also, what's the best way to run an SWF outside of a browser? gnash? swfdec? other?

Comment: The answer to your last question is Adobe Air.

Comment: This reminds me very much of the [chumby](http://www.chumby.com/)

Comment: I'm sure someone does... I saw one of those gambling bar app systems which always seem "flashy" to me rebooting centos the other day.

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo could be a good choice. Use flags can be really helpful to cut out all the unnecessary stuff. And once you done it, easy to maintain and keep it up2date.

Tiny Core is very small by default (~10 MB, Micro Core is ~6 MB). I recommend to take a look at these too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something *really* (I mean really) tiny, check out [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). I've build over 6 system with it (custom servers), and it's amazingly small and fast (if you build it to be).

The downside is that it takes a really long to build & compile, but if you're up for it, go ahead. I warn you, though, that you have to configure *everything* in the system.

One build for me takes 8 hours (unattended completely), so go and get a coffee (or 4) while you wait.